# Find and Replace a File Path in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm currently working on an Excel file which has to be regularly updated with fresh data.

The data source is a CSV file.

With VBA, I open the CSV File, transform the data into a named table.
The Excel contains the previous data source path which needs to be replaced by the new one.

To make the task easier, I put the previous data source path in cell C11 in the sheet "ACTUALISATION", so i just fetch the old data source there and replace in every other worksheet the old data source by the new one.

The problem I have is the old data source is not replaced correctly every where, which is quite odd as the replace parameters are the same as the manual find and replace method with CTRL+H.

Any idea why/how this happens?

```
Sub ActualiserTout()   
    Dim exportGalaxy As String
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim reportingWS(1 To 5) As String
    Dim aRemplacer As String
    Dim remplacement As String

    exportGalaxy = v360FilePath()

    reportingWS(1) = "Graphs Fenêtre Eval"
    reportingWS(2) = "Graphs V360 FO - EPICs"
    reportingWS(3) = "Graphs V360 BO - EPICs"
    reportingWS(4) = "Graphs V360 FO - Evolution"
    reportingWS(5) = "Graphs V360 BO - Evolution"

    aRemplacer = Worksheets("ACTUALISATION").Cells(11, 3).Value
    remplacement = Chr(39) & exportGalaxy & Chr(39) & "!"

    If exportGalaxy = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open exportGalaxy, Delimiter:=4, Local:=True

    Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
    tbl.Name = "DonnéesBrutes"

    Workbooks("DATA_V360-1.xlsm").Activate

    For Each ws In reportingWS
        Worksheets(ws).Cells.Replace _
        What:=aRemplacer, _
        Replacement:=remplacement, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next

    Worksheets("ACTUALISATION").Cells(11, 3).Value = Chr(39) & remplacement
End Sub

Function v360FilePath()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "CSV Files", "*.csv", 1

        If .Show = True Then
            'Récupère le chemin, nom et extension du fichier sélectionné
            v360FilePath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "no file selected"
        End If

    End With
End Function
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
I try to replace the data coming from `Export(4).csv` by `Export(3).csv`

In first worksheet the path/fileName/extension is replaced correctly everywhere

```
=NB.SI.ENS('C:\Users\E15378\Downloads\Export(4).csv'!DonnéesBrutes[ReponseQ1]; "=2"; 'C:\Users\E15378\Downloads\Export(4).csv'!DonnéesBrutes[debutCas]; ">="&[@[Date Semaine]]; 'C:\Users\E15378\Downloads\Export(4).csv'!DonnéesBrutes[debutCas]; "<"&[@[Date Semaine]]+7)
```

In the "EPICs" worksheets, only the 2 first cells of the 1st table get replaced correctly and in the "Evolution" worksheets, none get replaced.

This is in one of the two first cells:

```
=NB.SI.ENS('C:\Users\E15378\Downloads\Export(3).csv'!DonnéesBrutes[clickFacturation];">0"; 'C:\Users\E15378\Downloads\Export(3).csv'!DonnéesBrutes[formatVision360]; "pop-up"; 'C:\Users\E15378\Downloads\Export(3).csv'!DonnéesBrutes[fluxBandeau]; ">7,49912E+11")*100/B9
```

And in after the 2nd cell and for the rest, nothing gets replaced:

```
=SOMME.SI.ENS('C:\Users\E15378\Downloads\Export(4).csv'!DonnéesBrutes[Temps affichage EPIC Facturation]; 'C:\Users\E15378\Downloads\Export(4).csv'!DonnéesBrutes[formatVision360]; "pop-up"; 'C:\Users\E15378\Downloads\Export(4).csv'!DonnéesBrutes[fluxBandeau]; ">7,49912E+11")/NB.SI.ENS('C:\Users\E15378\Downloads\Export(4).csv'!DonnéesBrutes[Temps affichage EPIC Facturation]; ">0"; 'C:\Users\E15378\Downloads\Export(4).csv'!DonnéesBrutes[formatVision360]; "pop-up"; 'C:\Users\E15378\Downloads\Export(4).csv'!DonnéesBrutes[fluxBandeau]; ">7,49912E+11")
```

Comment: where is it not replaced correctly?

Comment: Sidenote: Your use of variables could lead to some confusion `For Each ws In reportingWS` is usually used like `For each ws in NameofWorkbook.Worksheets` looping through sheets instead of looping through index numbering.

Comment: @JvdV i have to use this method because there are many other worksheets and i do not want to loop through them as the time required to find/replace in some worksheets takes too long and is not useful. So i just add to an array the files on which i need to do this operation

Comment: @RonRosenfeld look in edit, i will give you an example of what happens when i launch the macro

Comment: Hard for me to tell.  Try: 1. Put `Option Explicit` at beginning of macro to ensure you declare properly all variables.  2. Get rid of `.Activate` and refer to workbook directly. 3. Set a breakpoint and step through the code, to ensure you are referencing what you should be at each step (and doublecheck what the variables contain at each step).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'll try that thanks :)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld did all what you tried and nothing works. I even tried recording a macro and then replacing the values by parameters, and i get the same result as before. It seems that the variables values may be the problem which is odd as some paths still get replaced

Comment: Without testing in your environment, troubleshooting will be tough.  Replacement of some, but not all, paths point to differences in the cells being tested.  But your going to need to check the references in a step-by-step fashion to ascertain exactly where the problem lies.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I was still unable to find the problem, but i found another simpler way to do the same thing: instead of replacing the path with code, i simply used the "modify links" function in excel situated in the "Data" tab. It does what is needed without error and faster too. Thanks for your help :)